# Button not saving state onResume

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, onresume

I have just started Android development. I have a very simple project. I have a button and a textview. When I click the button, the text of the textView changes and button is disabled. This part is working fine. However I want the button to maintain its state (disabled state) if I press home on phone (Escape on keyboard) and go back to my app. But in my case, Button gets enabled every time I press home and get back to my app. Here is the code

```
package com.mypack.textmanipulation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnChangeText;
    private boolean check;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnChangeText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText);
        check = true;

        setButtonOnClickInterface();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        checkButtonIsEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickInterface()
    {

        btnChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    txtView.setText("Text Changed");
                    btnChangeText.setEnabled(false);
                    check = false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkButtonIsEnabled()
    {
        if (check)
        {
            btnChangeText.setEnabled(true);

        }
        else
        {
            btnChangeText.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


}
```

Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Please read the Activity life cycle documentation, in particular onPause() and onResume().

Comment: your problem get solved or not?

Comment: did you tried to debug the value of check?

Comment: I have already gone through activity life cycle. onResume is gonna call when activity is running in the background and gains focus again. Thats exactly how i programmed the project but still not working

Comment: hi razziq,there is a issue for me.Actually in my case, there are 3 buttons, when the User clicks on any button  it should perform only one action one time and then all 3 buttons should disable permanetly.When we reopen the same application the buttons should be in disable state.How can i do that ?       Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just found the solution. I was exiting the app instead of pausing it. Actually i was presing the ESC button on the keyboard to go back to HOME screen which is actually equivalent to the BACK button in Android and in my case, i guess, the app was exiting, so every time i tapped the app icon again, onCreate event is been called instead of onResume.

BTW HOME button on Keyboard acts as Android HOME button.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared Preference in your project to store values [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)